# Rails 6 not serving static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've just upgraded a rails 5.1 project to Rails 6 and finally got it to render views. However, I still can't get Puma (4.3.3) to serve static files from the `public/` folder. I opted for using Sprockets 4.0 instead of Webpack due to the difficulty of setting it up. I get this error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound - The asset "intro_video.mp4" is not present in the asset pipeline.:
  app/views/home/_intro_video.html.haml:1
  app/views/home/index.html.haml:52

Started POST "/__better_errors/82e7c6297114c48a/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-02 09:05:05 -0400
```

I'm in the development environment and have added `config.serve_static_assets = true`
 to my `config/environments/development.rb` and rebooted the server. The page in question is linking to 'intro_video.mp4' which is in the root of the `public/` folder. If I put `localhost:3000/intro_video.mp4` directly into Firefox I get a `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] \"/intro_video.mp4\"` error.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I've tried moving the `intro_video.mp4` file to my `app/assets/images` directory but now I get this strange issue:

> SassC::SyntaxError at /
>
> Error: Undefined variable: "$light-gray".
>           on line 15:10 of app/assets/stylesheets/datepicker.scss
>      color: $light-gray;

Which means that the `@import 'variables'` line in my `application.scss` does not work, but all the other files referenced there work. In fact, if I add any files to my `app/assets/images` directory this happens. This makes no sense to me...

EDIT (again): So I fixed the CSS issue by removing this from `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

...which was affecting the load order of my stylesheets
Still can't get anything to work from the `public/` directory, so I'll just settle by moving everything to `app/assets/images`.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 6, the following should work:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```